# Why does location.toString() report the same as location.href?

Tags: javascript

The window.location is an object. But when you execute `location.toString()` it converts the object to the equivalent to `location.href`.

My question is how? And can I set up objects to a similar behaviour?

Comment: All objects have a toString() method. You can override it either by changing the prototype implementation, or the implementation for the concrete instance. You should be more precise as to what you want to do.

Comment: To complement @jjrdk's comment: For `window.location`, the `toString()` method is implemented in such a way that it returns the `href` property.

Comment: To complement @Tomalak answer, here is the proof https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/toString

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a `toString` method to your object that returns what you want. In that case `href`

eg:

```
var obj = {
  href:'',
  toString:function(){
    return this.href;
  }
};

obj.href = 'http://stackoverflow.com';
obj.toString();
```